# PyYAML add string to list

Tags: python, string, list, yaml, pyyaml

I'm pretty new to PyYAML and don't understand everything about it. I have a YAML file with a list;

```
the-list:
  - "string1"
  - "string2"
  - "string3"
```

I have managed to find out how to fetch the list in my python file, but not how to add another string on to it, and save it to the YAML file. So it would become

```
the-list:
  - "string1"
  - "string2"
  - "string3"
  - "newstring"
```

Help appreciated! Here's the code I use for reading the YAML file:

```
with open('config.yml', 'r') as f:
    config = yaml.load(f)

LIST = config["the-list"]
```

Comment: Mind to share the code you use to fetch the list? Once the list is in python, it becomes a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) and can be modified, e.g. items could be `append`ed.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qErKDuEE

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Any ideas on how I should do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had given a clue to the `list` datatype in my comment. Simply `append` the new item to the list:

```
config["the-list"].append("newstring")
with file('config.yml', 'w') as f:
    yaml.dump(config, f)
```